# Azure Service Bus : Amqp Idle Timeout

Tags: java, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to find a way to increase Amqp Idle Timeout in Azure Service Bus but am not able to.

I am using the default Message Handler Options - one of the option is to set the maxAutoRenewDuration which is defaulted to 5 minutes. The timeout that is occurring  is after 10 minutes of duration, so think, this option (maxAutoRenewDuration) does not relate to this idle timeout. Is there any where else I can set this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lock lost exception will be thrown if message is not handled within 5 minutes. This is where `maxAutoRenewDuration` can be helpful. As for for AMQP idle time (or wait time), it is not exposed by the high level API which Message Handler is. I would look at the client and message sender / receiver.

Comment: Indeed increasing the value for maxAutoRenewDuration fixed this issue.